# How do you make a single time series from 3 separate non overlapping time series in R?

Tags: time-series

my goal is to create a simulated time series composed of three time series each with the same $p,d,q$ but with different standard deviations then fit an arima (which will not fit by design). i.e i want to make a heteroskedastic time series in R.
here's my problem my $R$ coding is terrible and so far i can create the three component series but merging them wont let me fit an arima as the resulting series looks like this:

Time Series:

Start $= 1 $

End $= 150 $

Frequency $= 1$

```
    tssd2     lagsd5    lagsd7
```

1 13.372035         NA        NA

2  8.824530         NA        NA

3  9.839556         NA        NA

4  8.364246         NA        NA

5 10.417347         NA        NA

6  9.762639         NA        NA

7  9.613973         NA        NA

8 10.524904         NA        NA

9 10.219140         NA        NA

10 11.817886         NA        NA

11 11.931814         NA        NA

12 11.192222         NA        NA

13  7.849955         NA        NA

14  9.166595         NA        NA

15  7.709941         NA        NA

16  7.270403         NA        NA

17  9.227334         NA        NA

18  7.620949         NA        NA

19  8.424921         NA        NA

20  9.229309         NA        NA

21  7.133997         NA        NA

22  6.906854         NA        NA

23  7.268167         NA        NA

24  7.415594         NA        NA

25  5.547073         NA        NA

26  6.558708         NA        NA

27  6.872302         NA        NA

28  8.928793         NA        NA

29  9.559935         NA        NA

30 11.171813         NA        NA

31  7.947032         NA        NA

32  8.181449         NA        NA

33  9.500626         NA        NA

34  6.868109         NA        NA

35  7.448251         NA        NA

36  6.720343         NA        NA

37  7.977832         NA        NA

38 10.942365         NA        NA

39 10.409160         NA        NA

40 10.920467         NA        NA

41  9.717640         NA        NA

42 11.699293         NA        NA

43 10.796548         NA        NA

44  8.462440         NA        NA

45 10.024658         NA        NA

46 11.116045         NA        NA

47 10.488177         NA        NA

48  8.259003         NA        NA

49  9.461125         NA        NA

50 10.367036         NA        NA

51        NA  6.4219875        NA

52        NA 11.0830306        NA

53        NA 14.5777664        NA

54        NA 19.6244908        NA

55        NA 11.9813102        NA

etc
what can i do to make it into one long time series?